# boot from external drive

Tags: boot, multi-boot

I have Linux Mint installed on my laptop, and now I need to work with Windows as well. For several reasons, I don't wish to repartition my disk, so I wonder if it is possible to boot and work with Windows from an external SSD.

If so, *(technical details are not requested)* is it a hard or a trivial task? Furthermore, is it a sound solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RUFUS create a bootable USB drive, then change the boot order to put USB at the top of the list.

Rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/